# Fastest way to delete files from a directory tree whose names contain a certain string

Tags: linux, bash, perl, shell, delete-file

I have a directory containing subdirectories from which I would like to delete any files whose names contain `out`. What is the fastest method of doing this?

I have tried several things.

A simple:

```
rm */*out*
```

Perl:

```
perl -e 'for ( <*/*out*> ) { ( (stat)[9] < (unlink) ) }'
```

Each of which seem to take a serious amount of time. For 1,000 subdirectories, each of which contain around 50 files matching `*out*`, it takes:

```
Perl:        ~25 mins
rm */*out* : ~18 mins
```

I also tried `rsync`, moving the files to a folder first and then syncing with delete, but that took ages.

Does anyone have a faster way of getting rid of these files, as this seems inordinately slow to me?

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, you are trying to delete only the files, and only those directly under your current directory or directly under the directories in your current directory. So for example you want to delete `out.txt` `./a/out.txt` but not `./a/out/` nor `./a/b/out.txt`.

Comment: What is `( (stat)[9] < (unlink) )` supposed to do? `(stat)[9]` is the modification time of the file, while `unlink` returns the number of files deleted, so I don't understand what you expect to achieve by comparing them in void context.

Comment: I don't think you're going to do any better than the `rm` command. Deleting 50,000 files shouldn't take that long; are these files on a network drive?

Comment: @Borodin - Not sure what  `( (stat)[9] < (unlink) )` is supposed to do, never used perl before. I found it on a post claiming it was the fastest way to achieve what I wanted [link](http://www.slashroot.in/which-is-the-fastest-method-to-delete-files-in-linux). @silel - I want to delete ./a/*out*, that's all the output files I need to get rid of.

Comment: The files are on a scratch partition of a hpc cluster.

Comment: In my case a `updatedb.mlocate` process was slowing down my delete operation by a factor of 5. So maybe have a look at your io with `iotop` , maybe some other process messes a round with your io before trying to optimize the delete functionality.

Answer (score 6):

I find `test3` is the fastest (11-25 sec). But why not test it yourself?

Your filesystem can have a big impact on the performance.

The test uses [GNU Parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/).

```sh
# Make test set: 150000 files, 50000 named *.seq
testset() {
  doit() { mkdir -p $1 ; cd $1 && parallel --results ./{} seq ::: {1..50}; }
  export -f doit
  seq 1000 | parallel --bar doit >/dev/null

  # Drop caches before starting a test
  echo 3 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches >/dev/null
}
export -f testset

# Define tests
test1() {
  find . -name '*seq' | perl -ne 'chop;unlink'
}
export -f test1
test2() {
  find . -name '*seq' -delete
}
export -f test2
test3() {
  find . -name '*seq' | parallel --pipe -N1000 -q perl -ne 'chop;unlink'
}
export -f test3
test4() {
  find . -name '*seq' -print0 | xargs -0 -P2 rm
}
export -f test4
test5() {
  find . -name '*seq' -print0 | xargs -0 rm
}
export -f test5
test6() {
  find . -name '*seq' | perl -e 'chomp(@a=<>);unlink @a'
}
export -f test6
test7() {
  # sort by inode
  ls -U -i */*seq* | sort -k1,1 -n| cut -d' ' -f2- | perl -e 'chomp(@a=<>);unlink @a'
}
export -f test7

# Run testset/test? alternating
eval parallel --joblog jl -uj1 ::: testset' 'test{1..7} 
# sort by runtime
sort -nk4 jl
```

Comment: Haven't uesd gnu parallel, but the test5 command seems to do the job fastest for me. ~89 sec. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your commands indeed seem to execute unusually slowly.

As for **what you tried**:

- `rm */*out*`:

  - is fine for smallish sets of matching files.
  - slows down for large sets of files and, more importantly, **runs the risk of *breaking* due to exceeding the max. command-line length**, as reported by `getconf ARG_MAX`, because the pattern (glob) `*/*out*` is expanded by the shell *up front*, and the resulting list of filenames is passed to external utility `rm` *at once*.
- I'm assuming that the `perl` command you *meant* to use is `perl -e 'unlink <*/*out*>'`:

  - In my tests it outperformed `rm */*out*`, but [YMMV](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/your_mileage_may_vary) (see below); it does have the distinct advantage of not being subject to the `getconf ARG_MAX` limit; however, it does slow down as the input set grows larger - see below.

---

- **Using *parallel* execution *can* help**:

  - **GNU and BSD/macOS `xargs` have a nonstandard `-P <n>` option** that allows running at most `<n>` instances of the specified command in parallel; *GNU* `xargs` supports `0` for `<n>`, which means that "xargs will run as many processes as possible", according to `man` page; while the specifics are unclear, and given that it also says, "Use the `-n` option or the `-L` option with `-P`; otherwise chances are that only one exec will be  done", in practice it does seem to make a difference.

    - **`find . -name '*out*' -print0 | xargs -0 -P0 rm` proved to be the fastest in my tests** - YMMV.
  - **[GNU Parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/)** - which is typically *not* preinstalled - is worth considering for sophisticated control of parallel execution in general, though it **may not help in this particular case**; it's a powerful tool, but not a magic bullet - YMMV.

---

Below is **a `bash` script that times various commands**; by default, it uses the following parameters:

- 1000 subfolders
- 50 files to delete in *each* subfolder
- an additional 100 files alongside the files to delete in each folder.

The script cleans up after itself and has no prerequisites other than `bash` (so you can run it on macOS as well, for instance); those tests that assume the presence of GNU `parallel` will simply fail if it's not present.
You can easily tweak the script by passing arguments from the command line or modifying the defaults, and by adding/removing commands to time.

---

The following are ***sample* timings** from a 2-core VMware Fusion VM running Ubuntu 16.04 on a macOS 10.12.4 host that's a late-2012 4-core Intel i5 3.2 Ghz machine with a Fusion Drive (hybrid SSD + HHD).

*Again: YMMV - there are numerous factors at play, such as filesystem, HDD, number of CPU cores, system load, ...*

```
find . -name '*out*' -print0 | xargs -0 -P0 rm                                       0.704
find . -name '*out*' -print0 | xargs -0 -P2 rm                                       0.745
find . -name '*out*' -print0 | xargs -0 rm                                           1.067
find . -name '*out*' | perl -e 'chomp(@a=<>); unlink @a'                             1.070
perl -e 'unlink <*/*out*>'                                                           1.089
find . -name '*out*' -delete                                                         1.094
find . -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -name '*out*' -delete                                 1.110
rm */*out*                                                                           1.369
find . -name '*out*' | parallel --pipe -n 1000 perl -nle 'unlink'                    1.460
find . -name '*out*' | parallel --pipe -n 1000 -q perl -e 'chomp(@a=<>); unlink @a'  1.493
find . -name '*out*' | parallel --xargs rm                                           2.294
find . -name '*out*' | parallel -n 1000 rm                                           2.465
```

Combining `find` with `xargs -P0` seems to be the winner here, and even `xargs` without parallel invocations is fast.

Perhaps surprisingly, the single-utility solutions (`rm`, `perl`) are *not* the fastest, and as the input set increases in size, parallel solutions become relatively faster.

Using GNU `parallel` doesn't help here, though it may with *larger* numbers.

---

Here's **the test script's source code**, whose only prerequisite is Bash v3+; a missing / different GNU `parallel` and/or the size of the `rm` command line exceeding the limit will simply be noted as such in the results.

```
#!/bin/bash

# ----- BEGIN: CUSTOMIZE HERE
numDirs=${1:-1000}       # Number of directories to create
numFilesPerDir=${2:-50}  # Number of target files per directory to delete
numFilesOtherPerDir=${3:-$(( numFilesPerDir * 2 ))} # Number of additional files per directory.

# Define the commands to test here, as you would execute them directly.
IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -ra cmdLines <<'EOF'
find . -name '*out*' -print0 | xargs -0 rm
find . -name '*out*' -print0 | xargs -0 -P2 rm
find . -name '*out*' -print0 | xargs -0 -P0 rm
find . -name '*out*' -delete
find . -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -name '*out*' -delete
perl -e 'unlink <*/*out*>'
find . -name '*out*' | perl -e 'chomp(@a=<>); unlink @a'
find . -name '*out*' | parallel --pipe -n 1000 -q perl -e 'chomp(@a=<>); unlink @a'
find . -name '*out*' | parallel --pipe -n 1000 perl -nle 'unlink'
find . -name '*out*' | parallel -n 1000 rm
find . -name '*out*' | parallel --xargs rm
rm */*out*
EOF

# ----- END: CUSTOMIZE HERE

# Set up execution of the teardown function on exit.
keepTmpDir=0
trap '(( keepTmpDir )) || teardownOnExit' EXIT

# Initial, one-time setup.
setupInitial() {
  tmpDir=/tmp/test-$$
  [[ -e $tmpDir ]] && { echo "Directory $tmpDir already exists. To run these tests, remove it first." >&2; exit 2; }
  mkdir "$tmpDir" && cd "$tmpDir" || exit
}

# Teardown on overall exit.
teardownOnExit() {
  # echo "Removing $tmpDir..."
  rm -rf "$tmpDir"
}

# Set up the dirs. and files for each test.
setupBeforeEachTest() {

  # To save time, only recreate the deleted files to set up for subsequent
  # test runs.
  local recreateFilesOnly=0
  [[ -d '1' ]] && recreateFilesOnly=1

  local dirNames=( $(seq $numDirs) )

  local fileNames=( $(seq $numFilesPerDir) )
  local fileNames=( "${fileNames[@]/%/-out}" )

  (( recreateFilesOnly )) || fileNamesOther=( $(seq $numFilesOtherPerDir) )

  (( recreateFilesOnly )) || mkdir -p "${dirNames[@]}" || exit
  for d in "${dirNames[@]}"; do
    cd "$d"
    touch "${fileNames[@]}"
    (( recreateFilesOnly )) || touch "${fileNamesOther[@]}"
    cd ..
  done

  # Activate the next line to inspect the temp. dir. before each test run.
  # showInFileManager "$PWD"; read -p "Attempting to show '$PWD' in the file manager; press Enter to continue."

}

# Verify that the most recent test ran correctly.
verifyAfterEachTest() {
  local count=$(find . -name '*out*' | wc -l)
  (( count == 0 )) || { echo "  ERROR: There are still $count '*out*' file(s) present." >&2; return 1; }
}

# --- Generic helper functions

showInFileManager() {
  local dir=$1
  case $(uname) in
    Linux)
      xdg "$dir"
      ;;
    Darwin)
      open "$dir"
      ;;
    *)
      echo "WARNING: Don't know how to open a dir. in the platform's file manager on  $(uname)." >&2
      ;;
  esac  
}

# Helper function for resetting the disk cache between runs.
resetDiskCache() {
  case $(uname) in
    Linux)
      sudo sync && echo 3 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches >/dev/null
      ;;
    Darwin)
      sudo sync && sudo purge    
      ;;
    *)
      echo "ERROR: Don't know how to clear caches on $(uname)." >&2
      exit 1
      ;;
  esac
}

# ==== MAIN BODY

setupInitial || exit

cat <<EOF

Tests will run in dir. $tmpDir, which will be removed on termination.

Parameters:
  # of subdirs.:                         $numDirs
    # of target files in each subdir.:   $numFilesPerDir
    # of other files in each subdir.:    $numFilesOtherPerDir

EOF

# To reset the disk cache, we need `sudo` - prompt up front.
sudo -v -p 'Please enter your password to allow clearing the disk cache between runs, which requires `sudo`: ' || exit 2

# Make `time` report total time elapsed only.
TIMEFORMAT='%3R'

quiet=0  # Set this to 1 to suppress the status messages
{
  # Loop over all tests
  for cmdLine in "${cmdLines[@]}"; do
    (( quiet )) || echo ">> $cmdLine <<"
    (( quiet )) || echo "  setting up..."
    setupBeforeEachTest || exit
    resetDiskCache || exit
    (( quiet )) || echo "  running..."
    timing=$({ time eval "$cmdLine"; } 2>&1 1>/dev/tty)
    (( quiet )) || echo "  verifying..."
    if verifyAfterEachTest; then
      echo "  OK"
    else
      echo "  FAILED"
      timing=$'(n/a)\t'"$(sed '$d' <<<"$timing")"
    fi
    printf '%s\t%s\n' "$cmdLine" "$timing" >&3
  done 3>&1 >/dev/tty
  (( quiet )) || echo "--- RESULTS (in secs., fastest first) ---" >/dev/tty
  # Sort and columnate the results below.
} |
  sort -t$'\t' -k2,2n |
    column -s$'\t' -t
```

Answer (score 1):

To remove all files with a single rm (using `find`):

`find /path/to/dir -name "*out*" -exec rm {} +`

Comment: I don't think he'll gain anythin by doing that, using a 'single' rm is already what the OP does. Maybe he can gain a little time by starting to delete files as he find them.

Comment: Basically you’re just writing `rm */*out*` in a more complicated way.

Comment: @silel: Terminating `-exec` with `+` rather than `\;` is what passes as many filenames as will fit to a _single_ invocation of `rm`, which makes a big difference. In the typical case - unless your platform has an unusually low command-line length limit and/or your list of filenames is very large - that'll result in a _single_ `rm` call _overall_.

Comment: Also, in `rm */*out*` the wildcard expansion is done by the shell, that's why `find` will perform better

Comment: @fedterzi: Why should `find` be faster than the shell?

Comment: @mklement0 and I don't think running it all in a single `rm` is a good thing, you have to wait for the lookup part of `find` to terminate before actually deleting anything.

Comment: @sile: While that is technically true, why would that matter here? But I agree that - if supported by one's `find` implementation (Linux, BSD/macOS) - using the nonstandard `-delete` action is preferable. This answer's `-exec rm {} +` approach is POSIX-compliant. (Btw, I misread your original comment about the single `rm` call - I mistakenly thought that you thought `rm` was invoked _once per filename_).

Comment: @mklement0 No trouble. My idea is that if we found the fastest lookup command, (and assuming `rm` is the fastest deleting command), to go any faster, we will have to do some operations in parallel. One way to go is to run the lookup and the deletion in parallel. A probably even better way would be to parallelize the lookup itself (for example by running multiple find commands, each on a subset of the directories).

Comment: @Borodin: `rm */*out*` not only slows down compared to `find` as the input set grows larger, but more importantly it runs the risk of exceeding the max. command-line length; see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I once had a similar problem with a tool that went berserk and left 400.000 temporary files behind after some time.
I experimented a lot with `rm *`, `find . -name ... -exec rm {} +` and some Perl solutions.

Surprisingly to me this was by far the fastest approach:

- determine the filenames in Perl and store them in a list.
- call `unlink @list`

Example:

```
if ( my $dh = IO::Dir->new($dir) ) {
    my @files_to_delete = ();
    while ( my $file = $dh->read() ) {
        $file = "$dir/$file";
        if ( -f $file ) {
            push @files_to_delete, $file;
        }
    }
    $dh->close();

    my $deleted = unlink @files_to_delete;
    print "deleted $deleted files\n";
}
```

There are other ways to determine `@files_to_delete` (like `glob` etc.) but the crucial point is the `unlink @files_to_delete` step.
Call `unlink` with as many files as possible at once. There seems to be no limit in the number of files (except memory).

This actually surprised me because I thougt `rm *` (or its equivalents) would be faster than Perl's `unlink` – but it wasn't.

Answer (score -1):

What about:

```
find . -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -name '*out*' -delete
```

With `find . -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2` you get all elements with a depth of 2 within `.`, which means every file inside a subdirectory of the current directory (`.`). In this case, a “file” can be anything: a regular file, a directory, a pipe, etc. you can add the `-type f` option if you want to remove regular files only:

```
find . -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -name '*out*' -type f -delete
```

With `-name '*out*'` you get all files which name contains `out`.

And `-delete` tells `find` to delete every file found. It should be noted that `-delete` is not supported by all versions of `find`, though it is very likely that your `find` already supports it.

Comment: without the `*` after `find`, or replace it with `path/to/dir`

Comment: `-delete` requires GNU find

Comment: @fedterzi: `-delete` also works with BSD/macOS `find`, but it's not POSIX-compliant.

Comment: To my surprise, constraining the hierarchy level at which deletion happens using `-mindepth` and `-maxdepth` does _not_ seem to help performance; please see my answer (and do tell us if your findings are different).